# ¿Cómo crear thumbnails de imágenes con PHP?

Tags: php, imagen, script

Quiero hacer que las imágenes sean más facil de cargar y quiero usar THUMBNAILS para eso estado buscando pero niguno me funcióno

este el CODE:

```
<img src="Thumb.php?file=image.png&width=100"></img>
```

**Thumb.php**

```
$file = @$_GET["file"]; 
$width = @$_GET["width"]; 

$file_info = getimagesize($file); 
// Obtenemos la relación de aspecto 
$ratio = $file_info[0] / $file_info[1]; 

// Calculamos las nuevas dimensiones 
$newwidth = $width; 
$newheight = round($newwidth / $ratio); 

// Sacamos la extensión del archivo 
$ext = explode(".", $file); 
$ext = strtolower($ext[count($ext) - 1]); 
if ($ext == "jpeg") $ext = "jpg"; 

// Dependiendo de la extensión llamamos a distintas funciones 
switch ($ext) { 
case "jpg": 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
break; 
case "png": 
$img = imagecreatefrompng($file); 
break; 
case "gif": 
$img = imagecreatefromgif($file); 
break; 
} 
// Creamos la miniatura 
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight); 
// La redimensionamos 
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $file_info[0], $file_info[1]); 
// La mostramos como jpg 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
imagejpeg($thumb, null, 80);
```

Comment: "No me funcionó" no alcanza para entender cuál es el problema que encontraste con esta solución. ¿Te tira un mensaje de error, una página en blanco, o algo?

Comment: una imagen rota

Comment: Lo de la imagen rota solamente significa que tu código no está generando un archivo de imagen válido, pero necesitamos un mensaje de error o algo así para poder resolver tu problema. "No anda" no es suficiente. Abrí la ruta de la imagen (thumb.php?file=image1.png&width=100) en el navegador y revisá si tira algún mensaje de error. Además revisá tu archivo phperror.log a ver si hay pistas ahí.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HLxQd

Comment: Asumiendo que la imagen está en el mismo directorio que el script, no es necesario concatenar el puntito. Reemplazá todas las instancias de **("." . $file)** por **($file)**

Comment: listo ahora sale esto http://imgur.com/vpj1kh4 pero en el link sigue rota <img src="thumb.php?file=image1.png&width=100" />

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que la imagen sigue rota? A mí me anduvo. Hacé un CTRL + F5 en tu navegador para refrescar, a ver si es un problema de caché. Y asegurate de no haber comentado la línea header() al final del archivo para debug ;)

Comment: ya y nada http://imgur.com/a/OCK4z cambie de navegador y ni eso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63386/discussion-between-leandro-barone-and-shareiv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando [Intervention:Image](https://github.com/Intervention/image)

```
// redimensionar imagen
$img->resize(320, 240);
```

Fácil y rápido

Comment: no me fuciono amigo

Comment: Estás usando composer? Mira los requisitos: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Comment: Si tengo todos los requisitos pero no quiero usar ningún plugin para este tipo de código porque lo quiero combinar con lo que ya tengo trabajado y llegar a usar un plugin Sería fácil pero no sé llegaría con los otros archivos que ya tengo trabajados

Comment: Quiero hacer que éste código funcione correctamente para la luego fusionarlo con lo que ya tengo Gracias por la ayuda amigo

Comment: Has probado esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596913/3994630

Comment: si ya lo probé pero no quiero que haga copias lo que quiero es que de la imagen originas la haga mas pequeña

Answer (score 1):

Esto es incorrecto:

```
// Ponemos el . antes del nombre del archivo porque estamos considerando que la ruta está a partir del archivo thumb.php
$file_info = getimagesize("." . $file);
```

No hay que concatenar el punto a la ruta. El script falla porque no puede encontrar la imagen. Reemplazá todas las veces que aparece esto en el código:

```
("." . $file)
```

Por esto:

```
($file)
```